# What is the difference between GitVersion.Tool and GitVersionTask

Tags: gitversion

I see that there are two nuget packages [GitVersion.Tool](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GitVersion.Tool/) and [GitVersionTask](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GitVersionTask/)

What is the difference between the two and what to use when.

I also see that [GitVersion](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GitVersion/), but looks like this is deprecated, because the last update was two and half years ago. So lets ignore that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe I am right in saying that the [GitVersion](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GitVersion/) package can be ignored.  This is no longer used, or recommended.

[GitVersion.Tool](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GitVersion.Tool/) is a .Net Global Tool version of GitVersion.  You can install this using globally on your machine using the following:

```
dotnet tool install --global GitVersion.Tool
```

This requires the prior install of the .Net Core CLI tools in order for it to work.  With both of these things installed, you can then run `dotnet-gitversion` to assert the version number of your repository.

[GitVersionTask](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GitVersionTask/) is a NuGet package that you would add to your project within Visual Studio.  It includes MSBuild Targets which runs GitVersion during the compilation stage, asserting the version numbers of the repository, which can then be used in other parts of the MSBuild build.

[GitVersion.CommandLine](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GitVersion.CommandLine/) is similar to the GitVersion.Tool package, with the exception that this is intended for use with full .Net Framework, and not .Net Core.

[GitVersion.portable](https://chocolatey.org/packages/gitversion.portable) is essentially the same as the GitVersion.CommandLine package, but it is shipped as a Chocolatey package.  This means that you can install is globally on your machine using the command:

```
choco install gitversion.portable
```

Comment: Appears that https://chocolatey.org/packages/GitVersion.Portable is alternative to https://www.nuget.org/packages/GitVersion.Tool/

Comment: It is true that it is an alternative, but not directly an alternative to GitVersion.Tool.  GitVersion.Tool requires the newer .Net Core Runtime in order to execute, where as gitversion.portable using the full .net framework.  The portable package is really an alternative to GitVersion.Commandline.  I have updated the answer with this information.

Comment: Do not foget to specify a version for te command: dotnet tool install --global --version 5.6.6 GitVersion.Tool